# How to use the google classroom api with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-classroom

So I'm trying to use to google-classroom api found in the npm [Google-classroom-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-classroom)

But I can't figure out what I have to do to make it work with my express.
First of all, do I need to login to a google account? It doesn't say how I am suppose to do that? Can I do it using passport.js and oauth? And if I just paste the code I get a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. Whats that about?

Comment: Hi. The npm page has a sample code to get started. If there are issues in it would be helpful if you could show us what you have tried and what error are you getting. Or please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: First of all I need to login to a google account. It doesn't say how I am suppose to do that? Can I do it using passport.js and oauth? And if I just paste the code I get a  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Comment: Assuming from the example code, the connection expects client id and secret key to authenticate and login. And looking at google classroom api page, it seems there is an option to generate the keys (https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth). You can try putting it together from there. Also it seems the question is about specific npm package rather than google-classrom api, in which case it would be better to put it on the github page of the package.